# How do I do this animated underline hover effect?

Tags: css, hover, underline

Can anyone help me work out how this cool animated underline hover effect is done on this [site](http://www.ryanrogalski.com/)? I have tried to replicate it myself but have not succeeded. here is my [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/carasikesu/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are hover the a href you need to write css and animation function for that you here you can refer my code

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    -webkit-animation: border-hover .6s infinite ease-in-out !important;
    animation: border-hover .6s infinite ease-in-out !important
}

@-webkit-keyframes border-hover {
    0%,
    100% {
        border-bottom-style: dotted
    }
    25%,
    50% {
        border-bottom-style: dashed
    }
    75% {
        border-bottom-style: solid
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes border-hover {
    0%,
    100% {
        border-bottom-style: dotted
    }
    25%,
    50% {
        border-bottom-style: dashed
    }
    75% {
        border-bottom-style: solid
    }
}

@-o-keyframes border-hover {
    0%,
    100% {
        border-bottom-style: dotted
    }
    25%,
    50% {
        border-bottom-style: dashed
    }
    75% {
        border-bottom-style: solid
    }
}

@keyframes border-hover {
    0%,
    100% {
        border-bottom-style: dotted
    }
    25%,
    50% {
        border-bottom-style: dashed
    }
    75% {
        border-bottom-style: solid
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class"link">Link goes here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with transition and apply a border property to your container

see snippet below

```css
body{
  background:black;
  color:orange;
}
#somethin{
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:solid transparent 5px;
  transition:all 1s;
}
#somethin:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  border-bottom:solid red 5px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="somethin">
Infinite Loop
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

since the support of CSS3 for text decoration style not working, I used border bottom, here's a sample code :

```
<!html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @keyframes cool-effect {
            from {
                border-bottom-style: solid;
            }
            50% {
                border-bottom-style: dotted;
            }
            to {
                border-bottom-style: dashed;
            }
        }

        .fancy {
            width : 300px;
            border-bottom : 2px solid #000;
        }
        .fancy:hover {
            -webkit-animation: cool-effect 1s infinite;
            -o-animation:cool-effect 1s infinite;
            animation: cool-effect 1s infinite;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="fancy">Underline awesome effect !</h2>
</body>
</html>
```